# How do I install Silverlight now that it has been discontinued?

Tags: internet-explorer, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a database application (developed with Visual Studio Lightswitch) which runs Silverlight.  I need to install the Lightswitch runtime and Silverlight on a Windows 10 computer but I get an error in Chrome and Firefox--404 file not found.  When I try to run Internet Explore it closes and Launches Edge.  Is there a way to install Silverlight now that it has been discontinued by Microsoft?
I have uninstall the Lightswitch app and Silverlight as well as deleted the "out of browser" directory in AppData.

This is the Microsoft download link that never works.

https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default?reason=unsupportedbrowser&_helpmsg=FirefoxObsoleteForSL&v=4.0#sysreq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE11 is going to be retired on Windows 10 in two weeks so you may as well fix this on Edge.

There's a standalone installer on CNET that still works - https://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Silverlight-64-bit/3000-2378_4-75884713.html . Install that.

In Edge, go to edge://settings/defaultBrowser. Enable "Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode". Don't Restart yet. Add your URL to the list underneath that option (there are other ways to enable IE Mode but if you have a known URL, this is the simplest). Use the Restart button now.

Load the site. It should now work (including Silverlight) in Edge IE Mode.

Edit: Reading your question again, it looks like you're using a desktop installed app. The above will work for a server hosted Lightswitch application. Some variation of it may work for an installed one but I don't have a setup to test that.

Comment: Thank you; especially for the "Internet Explorer" mode.  Once I figured out how to disable the Edge overrided setting Silverlight installed correctly and the "Desktop" Lightswitch app load right up.

Comment: Whatever became of Xamarin's SilverLight clone, MoonLight. Did it ever work?